# In React navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() giving wrong coordinates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-geolocation, google-maps

script used:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&libraries=places,geometry"></script>
```

Code used:

```
var options = {
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      timeout: 5000,
      maximumAge: 0
    };

    function success(pos) {
      var crd = pos.coords;

      console.log('Your current position is:');
      console.log(`Latitude : ${crd.latitude}`);
      console.log(`Longitude: ${crd.longitude}`);
      console.log(`More or less ${crd.accuracy} meters.`);
    }

    function error(err) {
      console.warn(`ERROR(${err.code}): ${err.message}`);
    }
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
```

Output :

```
Your current position is:
Latitude : 19.7514798
Longitude: 75.7138884
More or less 296997 meters.
```

Working on a react project where I need to show stores near me. I am using the above code to get my location coordinates this is working fine in a smartphone but in laptop (with GPS) browsers I am getting wrong coordinates. The distance between a current location and coordinates is about 130+ KM. Also, third party site used to find the current location also showing same location that of the coordinates.

Comment: `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` does not use GPS to get latitude and longitude. Mostly the location return by this api is the location of your internet service providers hub/center etc. don't rely on this api for accurate location.

Comment: @hussain.codes Can you suggest anything for finding location using GPS

Comment: Has anybody found a way to get accurate location?